# Why the automatic Riverpod provider for a StateNotifier is not a StateNotifierProvider?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, riverpod-generator

I'm writting a Flutter app with Riverpod architecture and I need a StateNotifier to keep track of an int that serve to save the current page of a multiscreen form.

Here is my StateNotifier code :

```dart
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'multi_step_controller.g.dart';

class MultiStepFormController extends StateNotifier<int> {
  MultiStepFormController() : super(0);

  void next() => state += 1;
  void previous() => state -= 1;
  void reset() => state = 0;
  void setIndex(int index) => state = index;
}
```

I wanted to use the Riverpod 3.0 syntax to automaticaly write the provider for this class with this code (and a build of course to generate the part file):

```
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
MultiStepFormController multiStepFormController(MultiStepFormControllerRef ref) {
  return MultiStepFormController();
}
```

But I end up with this error when I want to read the int :
`pageController.jumpToPage(currentIndex); The argument type 'MultiStepController' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.`

Instead, I changed the code for the provider by manually writting this :
    `final multiStepFormControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider<MultiStepFormController, int>((ref) { return MultiStepFormController(); });`

And now the code works as intended.

I just want to know why the automatic provider doesn't work like the one I wrote by hand so I can have a better use of automatic generated code from Riverpod in the future. Thanks in advance ! ;-)

Sorry for the code preview, I can't format it properly...

Comment: Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).  And the generators will NEVER generate the legacy tools.

Answer (score 1):

The generator doesn't support `StateNotifier`. Use a `Notifier/AysncNotifier` instead.

Below is the syntax for defining an equivalent `Notifier` using code generation.

```dart
@riverpod
class MultiStepFormController extends _$MultiStepFormController {
  @override
  int build() => 0;

  void next() => state += 1;
  void previous() => state -= 1;
  void reset() => state = 0;
  void setIndex(int index) => state = index;
}
```

Use `ref.watch(multiStepFormControllerProvider)` to watch the `Notifier`'s state.

Use `ref.read(multiStepFormControllerProvider.notifier)` to access the `Notifier`.

And remember not to declare a constructor for a `Notifier/AysncNotifier` class. The `Notifier/AysncNotifier` should be initialised using the `build` method.